# Resposnive centred hexagon honeycombe layout in specific order

Tags: css, responsive-design, hexagonal-tiles

I'm trying to create some hexagonal blocks with content in a specific layout. I have four block starting with one block at the top followed by a row of two then finishing with a row of one as depicted in the image below. The problem I have had with all the demo's i've found on the interweb is that the `<li>` uses `float:left`. I tried using `display:inline-block` and `display:inline` but neither worked. I also need it to be responsive so that the blocks go into rows of one on iPad portrait and below. Does anyone know of a solution to this problem or do I need to call the A-Team?

http://tandsdev.co.uk/_testing/hexagan_layout.png

Comment: Why is this post getting voted down? This is a genuine issue I have!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implements below code, you can try

```
body{
  font-family: 'Open Sans', arial, sans-serif;
  background:#fff;

}
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
#categories{
  overflow:hidden;
  width:100%;   /* you can change the width here */
  margin:0 auto;
}
.clr:after{
  content:"";
  display:block;
  clear:both;
}
#categories li{
  position:relative;
  list-style-type:none;
  width:27.85714285714286%; /* = (100-2.5) / 3.5 */
  padding-bottom: 32.16760145166612%; /* =  width /0.866 */
  float:left;
  overflow:hidden;
  visibility:hidden;

  -webkit-transform: rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
  transform: rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
}
#categories li:nth-child(3n+2){
  margin:0 1%;
}
#categories li:nth-child(6n+4){
  margin-left:0.5%;
}
#categories li:nth-child(6n+4), #categories li:nth-child(6n+5), #categories li:nth-child(6n+6) {
    margin-top: -6.9285714285%;
  margin-bottom: -6.9285714285%;

  -webkit-transform: translateX(50%) rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
  -ms-transform: translateX(50%) rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
  transform: translateX(50%) rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
}
#categories li:nth-child(6n+4):last-child, #categories li:nth-child(6n+5):last-child, #categories li:nth-child(6n+6):last-child{
  margin-bottom:0%;
}
#categories li *{
  position:absolute;
  visibility:visible;
}
#categories li > div{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  text-align:center;
  color:#fff;
  overflow:hidden;
  background: #000;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate(60deg);
  -ms-transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate(60deg);
  transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate(60deg);

    -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;

}

/* HEX CONTENT */
#categories li img{
  left:-100%; right:-100%;
  width: auto; height:100%;
  margin:0 auto;
}

#categories div h1, #categories div p{
  width:90%;
  padding:0 5%;
}
#categories li h1{
/*  bottom:110%;  */
  font-style:italic;
  font-weight:normal;
  font-size:1.5em;
  padding-top:50%;
  padding-bottom:100%;
}
#categories li h1:after{
    content:'';
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-1px; left:45%;
  width:10%;
  text-align:center;
  z-index:1;
  border-bottom:2px solid #fff;
}
#categories li p{
    padding-top:50%;
    top:10%;
    padding-bottom:50%;
}


/* HOVER EFFECT  */

#categories li div:hover h1 {

}

#categories li div:hover p{

}

</style>




<ul id="categories" class="clr">
  <li class="pusher"></li>
    <li>

      <div>
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum is simply</h1>
        <p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available</p>
    </div>
  </li>
   <li class="pusher"></li>
    <li>
   <div>
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum is simply</h1>
        <p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
   <div>
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum is simply</h1>
        <p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available</p>
    </div>
  </li>
   <li class="pusher"></li> <li class="pusher"></li>
     <li>
       <div>
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum is simply</h1>
        <p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available</p>
    </div>
  </li>



</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. i just needed to reset padding to 0 on `ul` and make the width 117% to make it central.

Comment: How do you make the gaps/spacing larger and hexagons larger?

Comment: 1 ) For the spacing you can edit from "#categories li:nth-child(3n+2){}"
2 ) For the width you can edit from "#categories li"